# How to load google charts in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create a directive that can be feed with data from a controller, and show google charts. But the following does not work:

```
<div google-chart gdata="test"></div>

angular.module('test').controller('myController', myController);

function myController($scope) {

    $scope.test = [
                 ['one', 'two', 'three'],
                 [1,2,3],
                 [4,5,6]
             ];
    });
};

angular.module('test').directive('googleChart', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            gdata: '='
        },
        link: function($scope, $elm, $attr) {

            console.log(gdata);
                var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(gdata);

                var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart($elm[0]);
                chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    }
});

google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
```

The console prints `undifined` and shows an error `Error: gdata is not defined`.

Why is gdata not defined? I have in the the `div` tag as well as in `scope` of the directive.?

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it as, there is no plunker or fiddler, but can you try using  `console.log($scope.gdata);` and

```
var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable($scope.gdata);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using something which is already there instead of creating everything from scrap.

https://github.com/angular-google-chart/angular-google-chart/blob/development/README.md

Comment: I'd prefer not having to add an additional library for just a simple google chart.

Comment: okay. I will create a simple fiddle for the same and share it with you